# IE8 transparent div over an image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I got a weird behaviour on IE8 for this

HTML:

```
<a class='main'>
  <img src='http://annawrites.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/color-explosion.jpg' />
  <div class='layer'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.main { display: block; position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
.main img { width: 100px; height: 100px; /*display: none;*/ }
.layer { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 50%; cursor: crosshair; }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HLua8/2/ (or open [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/HLua8/2/show/) in IE8)

On IE8, `.layer` (ie. the crosshair cursor) is only on the top left corner (it minimizes itself to the content, which is 3 x `&nbsp;`)

I noticed it works fine when I set `.main img` to `display:none` but I need the image

Could someone help me to make `.layer` shown on IE8 as big as it is supposed to be? (ie. 100% width 50% height, just like on other browsers)

Comment: if you can, put the html/css on a server somewhere so I can test there, but at first glance I see a div in an anchor, IE8 doesn't take too kindly to that, I don't think.

Comment: Yeah that might be why, I wonder if there is any workaround. Here is the page http://fiddle.jshell.net/HLua8/2/show/

Comment: take a look at http://fiddle.jshell.net/HLua8/4/show/ all I have done is add a background colour, and remove your new break spaces... but seems to fix the issue, albeit by introducing a new issue (background colour). Im just running ie9 in ie8 browser mode, so might not be correct..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much fiddling, the best solution I could come up with for you, is to create a blank/transparent image and use this as the background image for your layer.

add to your css:

```
.layer {background-image:url(blank.png);}    
.layer:hover{cursor: crosshair;}
```

an updated version of your document would look as follows:

css:

```
#container {
    margin:40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.main img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;left: 0px;
    width: 100%;height: 50%;
    background-image:url(img/blank.png);
}

.layer:hover{cursor:crosshair;}
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
   <a class='main' href="test.html"><img src='http://annawrites.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/color-explosion.jpg' /></a>
   <div class='layer'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! You don't need to change the HTML at all, just add `background-image:url(img/blank.png)` to `.layer` and it works! Thanks a lot!